# NodeJS database (mysql) connection vs. transaction management

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions, promise, connection

In NodeJS applications, what is the best strategy for managing number of connections when transactions are involved (mysql community version)?

So, this is my line of thinking -

1) Do not hand over control to an ORM
2) Treat connection as an expensive commodity
3) mysql module for nodejs appears to be creating more connections

Given that, if n promises are executing at the same time (single thread part is understood), each representing a transaction, I do not want each of them create n connections - that much is obvious - but what happens when a transaction needs to be rolled back on a connection, if a connection is shared between promises? ..I do not want one transaction to fail if a another one fails as well..I would expect the 'connection' object to be little more intelligent..such that when beginTransaction is called, it provides a localized context...but just want to confirm if this is the case - I am looking for some documentations. If not, some sort of FIFO queue to facilitate sequalizing these transactions appear to be the way forward - but don't we already have one? What are other strategies you folks deployed?

Comment: FYI - I am looking at this already - http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/transactions.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to you KnexJS, especially because of its [transaction supprt](http://knexjs.org/#Transactions) and built-in [connection pooling](http://knexjs.org/#Installation-pooling). I'm sure Sequelize handles this in some way as well.

The nice thing about knex is that you can pass this `transaction` object through your promise chain, and if any promise fails (**even from a non-DB error, like a business rule!**) the transaction promise will be rejected and everything is automatically rolled back.

I hope this helps you out and has "just worked" for us so far - we have not needed to delve into the management of a connection pool at this time.

Comment: Thanks Clay - will take a look